# Swift: Drawing a semi-transparent line with drawStroke(_:touch:)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-graphics

[image: Dotted line]

I am trying to draw a semi-transparent line using drawStroke(_:touch:). I have changed the alpha value for the context, but instead of lighter brush got a dotted line. I assume something is wrong with touch handling. Is there a way to avoid that?

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 0.0)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

// Draw previous image into context
image?.draw(in: bounds)

drawStroke(context, touch: touch)
// Update image
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}

fileprivate func drawStroke(_ context: CGContext?, touch: UITouch) {
let previousLocation = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
let location = touch.location(in: self)

// Calculate line width for drawing stroke
let lineWidth = lineWidthForDrawing(context, touch: touch)

// Set color
drawColor.setStroke()

//Change Alpha
context?.setAlpha(0.3)
context?.setBlendMode(.darken)

// Configure line
context?.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
context?.setLineCap(.round)


// Set up the points
context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: previousLocation.x, y: previousLocation.y))
context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y))
// Draw the stroke
context?.strokePath()

}
```

Comment: have you got any solution for that, please share.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the alpha while setting the `strokeColor` or directly to the object like `context?.setAlpha(0.3)` this will draw line with dots like op's image above, here is my workaround and it works perfect.

Just get the two imageViews and over lap the second one (tempImageView) and draw the image on it and pass it to main when touch end.

```
// declare
var opacity = 1.0
var isSwiping = false

@IBAction func drawLineWithAlpha(_ sender: UIButton){
    opacity = 0.7
}  

@IBAction func drawSimpleLine(_ sender: UIButton){
    opacity = 1.0
}
```

---

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
    isSwiping = true;
    drawLine(capMode: .round, touches: touches, blendMode: .normal)
}

func drawLine(capMode: CGLineCap, touches: Set<UITouch>, blendMode: CGBlendMode){

  let imageViewTouch:UIImageView = self.tempImageView

  if let touch = touches.first{

     let currentPoint = touch.location(in: imageViewTouch)
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageViewTouch.frame.size, false, 0)
     imageViewTouch.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageViewTouch.frame.size.width, height: imageViewTouch.frame.size.height))          
     UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.move(to: CGPoint(x: lastPoint.x, y: lastPoint.y))
     UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: currentPoint.x, y: currentPoint.y))

     UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.setLineCap(capMode)
     UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.setLineWidth(8.0)

     UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.setStrokeColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
     UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.setBlendMode(blendMode)
     UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.strokePath()
     imageViewTouch.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
     imageViewTouch.alpha = opacity
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
     lastPoint = currentPoint

  }  
}
```

---

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,
                           with event: UIEvent?){

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mainImageView.frame.size)
    mainImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)

    tempImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: .normal, alpha: opacity)
    mainImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    tempImageView.image = nil

    print("touchesEnded")
    if(!isSwiping) {
        // code for touch end 
    }
}
```

*Delivered this ans just to update the SO repository.*